# Deserialize XML to Lists in C#

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have a set of classes with the following structure: **Plan > Elements > List<Element>**

```
[Serializable, XmlRoot("Plan")]
public class Plan
{
    public Plan()
    {
        elements = new Elements();
    }

    public int floor {get; set}; 

    [XmlElement("elements")]
    public Elements elements { get; set; }
}

[Serializable, XmlType("elements")]
public class Elements
{
    public Elements() { Items = new List<Element>(); }
    [XmlElement("element")]
    public List<Element> Items { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Element
{
    public int id { get; set; }
}
```

All this serializes fine using System.Xml.Serialization into this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Plan xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <elements>
    <element>
      <id>0</id>
    </element>
  </elements>
</Plan>
```

But when I try to deserialize it back again, the Elements class does not get populated at all and the result after a Serialize->Deserialize->Serialize procedure looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Plan xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <floor>0</floor>
    <elements />
</Plan>
```

This is my deserialization function:

```
public class Program {
    public Plan plan;

    public static void deserializeXml<T>(this T toDeserialize, string filename)
    {
       XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(toDeserialize.GetType());

       Stream stream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
       toDeserialize = (T) xmlSerializer.Deserialize(stream);
    }

    public void loadXml() {
        deserializeXml(plan, "plan.xml");
    }
}
```

Can someone give me a clue why this won't work? Thanks!

Comment: Read [ask] and provide a [mcve]. You're probably passing an incorrect `T` to `SerializeXml()` or `DeserializeXml()`. Especially the `floor` element appearing out of nowhere seems to hint towards that.

Comment: What is `floor`? I also think that you´re doing more than you´re showing here.

Comment: `floor` is a property of `Plan` that I missed to include in my minimal example. I have now updated my post to complete the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got your code working with minor modifications that have nothing to do with serialization itself, hence the issue doesn't seem to be with the xml serialization itself but with how it is called:

```
public static void deserializeXml<T>(this T toDeserialize, string filename)
{
   // !!!! toDeserialize is a copy to instance in the heap, so -> ...

   XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(toDeserialize.GetType());

   Stream stream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
   // -> ... here we assign reference of deserialized instance to toDeserialize(which is a copy)
   toDeserialize = (T) xmlSerializer.Deserialize(stream);

   // we need to return result here, otherwise this reference copy will be left dying here
}
```

The code:

```
static class Serializer
{
    // note here: deserializeXml returns reference to deserialized instance
    public static T deserializeXml<T>(string filename)
    {
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

        using (Stream stream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        {
            var toDeserialize = (T)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(stream);
            return toDeserialize;
        }
    }

    public static void serializeToXml<T>(T instance, string filename)
    {
        var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(instance.GetType());
        using (Stream stream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.Read))
        {
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(stream, instance);
        }
    }
}
```

So running it in the following way:

```
    Plan p = new Plan();
    p.elements.Items.Add(new Element { id = 1 });
    p.elements.Items.Add(new Element { id = 2 });
    p.elements.Items.Add(new Element { id = 3 });

    Serializer.serializeToXml(p, @"D:\1.xml");
    var p2 = Serializer.deserializeXml<Plan>(@"D:\1.xml");
    Console.WriteLine(p2.elements.Items.Count);
    Serializer.serializeToXml(p2, @"D:\2.xml");
```

gives identical `D:\1.xml` and `D:\2.xml` in the end.
Hope this helps

Comment: You were absolutely right! I never assigned the new deserialized Plan object. Thank you!